# Look at the tar log contents without extracting them

Tags: linux, tar

`tar -tvf file.tar` contains log files.
Is there anyway to do something like this

```
tar -tvf file.tar | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs less {}
```

This would give file not found, but is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use the `v` switch with `tar`, you'll just get a list of file names, not an `ls -l` listing.
I'm assuming you only want to look at the first file from the `head -1`
so

```
tar xfO file.tar `tar tf file.tar | head -1` |less
```

Will work to view the first file

That last switch is an uppercase 'O' Oh not 0
    `-O, --to-stdout` extracts files to standard output

If you want to view them all at once

```
tar xfO file.tar | less
```

But you'll lose the exact name of the log file you're viewing

Comment: It is saying tar:Options `[0-7][lmh]' not supported by *this* tar. I might not have the right tar version. vim is working for me, but that will result in a massive head-ache for memory I suppose.

Comment: my bad it is capital o, it is working.

Comment: Showing O vs. 0 properly has been discussed on meta, sorry for not making that clear

Answer (score 3):

You can open a tar in vim, browse its file structure, and read the files. (I'm sure emacs can do it too).

Answer (score 2):

[AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) is a virtual filesystem (based on [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)) that allows you to see inside archives as if they were directories.

Run `mountavfs` once and for all (it'll persist until the next reboot; you should put it in your `~/.profile`). This creates a view of the whole filesystem rooted at `~/.avfs`. Inside this view, every archive has an associated directory whose name has an extra `#` at the end. This directory contains the contents of the archive.

```
mountavfs
less ~/.avfs$PWD/file.tar\#/filename.log
```